# Any other way to terminate a string in javascript other than double quotes when begun with double quotes?

Tags: javascript

E.G.

```
<script>

a="MY INPUT";

</script>
```

So I am filtering the double quotes ' " ' to ensure that input cannot breakout. An alternative would be to apply an escape '\"'.  Is there another string terminator in javascript that could terminate a string begun with double quotes that I am unaware of? I know that the nullbyte doesn't apply.

Thanks

Comment: Not according to the spec: http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4.

Comment: @Felix Kling, you should post it as an answer so I can award the points

Comment: Newline and carriage return characters need to be escaped too.

Comment: @nnnnn why? these don't escape the string it appears

Comment: A newline character in a JS string literal is a syntax error. You have to put \n instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use single quotes as well:

```
var a = 'my string';
```

Comment: A single quote does not appear to terminate a string begun with a doulb equote

Comment: It doesn't use a single quote to start as well. What exactly are you asking then?

Comment: @user1166981 if you start a string with `"` then you must terminate it with `"`, if you start with `'` then you must terminate with `'`

Comment: See my updated question- I am trying to stop input breaking my string, i.e. terminating the string and breaking the code. e.g. "input"" would break it.

Comment: @des, so as long as the " is filtered properly there is no way to break the string?

Comment: I'm aware of only two ways of termiating a string and yes, if your string is between double quotes, then you should escape all double quotes inside string.

Comment: @user1166981: What do you mean by "break the string"? As nnnnnn mentioned in his comment, if you have a literal line break in your string, it will result in a syntax error. So, the answer to your question might depend on what your final goal is (which is not clear).

Comment: @ felix, for example: "hello" is fine, "\"hello" is fine, "";alert('oh oh'); is not fine. Is there someway this could happen if a \n is used in the input? (to the effect that someone could break the string and run their own code.

Comment: @user1166981: Where does "the input" come from? Are you using a server-side language to inject user-entered data into your Javascript?

Comment: @nnnnn It's coming from the server which originates from a POST method request via html.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes.

```
<script>

 a='MY INPUT';

 </script>
```

This one also will work

```
 $("#purchase").html('<option value="1">Classics</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x7.8.4), there are or only two ways to define string literals:

> *StringLiteral* ::
>        `"` *DoubleStringCharacters*<sub>opt</sub> `"`
>        `'` *SingleStringCharacters*<sub>opt</sub> `'`

So, it seems that double quoted strings can only be terminated by double quotes.